# sendDocument using file_id as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I can successfully send a file hosted on my server by simply defining the path. However, according to the node-telegram-bot-api, you can also send a document which is already hosted on the telegram servers by simply passing the file_id in the doc parameter as seen [here](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api#TelegramBot+sendDocument). i obtained a simple text file's id using @fileidbot and passed it in the doc variable. I did not receive the file. What could I be doing wrong.

```js
bot.on('message', function (msg) {
  var chatId = msg.chat.id;
  var doc = 'BQADBAADjwADaRsPCBXEI_UPjlH8Ag';
  bot.sendDocument(chatId, doc);
});
```

where `BQADBAADjwADaRsPCBXEI_UPjlH8Ag` is the `file_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a file using file_id if that file was not created by your bot or was not sent to your bot by a user.